# Accessing script file stored in Miscellaneous Folder of SSIS

Tags: ssis, relative-path

I would like to store some `sql` scripts on **miscellaneous folder** and need to execute those in `ssis package`. But I'm unable to find a way to access files in **miscellaneous folder**.

**Note** : Using project deployment model. So access using the full path will not help

Comment: when the .ispac is created, the files in misc aren't bundled along.   a network share can sometimes fit the bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the .ispac is created, the files in misc aren't bundled along.

Hence, for project deployments we can use the files inside miscellaneous folder

thanks for the answer @vhoang on comment